# Drag and drop image layers on a background in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I have a requirement of creating an asp.net webpage that the user is able to dynamically add new defined image objects (increase the amount) on a background image.

Then the user can drag and drop the image objects on the background image. The coordinates of the images objects will then be saved. In addition, a new background image contain the image objects will be saved in one image as well.

Would it be possible to be done with asp.net without Silverlight?

Comment: Will the images be already predefined or will the user upload the images and then they will be displayed on the page for the user to drag them around?

Comment: for example, there are two types of image: image A and image B. when the user increases/decreases the amount of image A, then they will be added or removed from the background image as well. Thanks @lcarus!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to me [that jQuery is a good tool](http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/) for this, specifically the draggable feature linked.

You can handle the events (start,stop,drag,create) appropriately and trigger a server-side action via ajax to save whatever information you need in the database.

In short, you should be able to detect when an image has been added/removed/dragged using regular javascript (and/or jQuery) and issue an ajax request to handle the appropriate action. It doesn't seem to me the Silverlight is required for this.

**UPDATE**: Adding more references.

[Look at this example](http://encosia.com/using-jquery-to-directly-call-aspnet-ajax-page-methods/) on how to call server-side functions using jQuery.

[Here's another example.](http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/ajax/Using-jQuery-with-ASP-NET.aspx)

Comment: probably, that is a good point to start with. Thanks lcarus, however, after having all objects (images saved in a list of javascript). how can I send those objects to the server to save them?

Comment: @JoesyXHN Look at my update. I posted 2 examples linked from 2 different websites. It's really simple. The first tutorial shows how to do it with PageMethods; the second link shows how to do it with Web Services. You can use either approach.